# Install Windows 10 from scratch on surface pro

Tags: windows, microsoft-surface

I accidentally cleaned everything on Surface Pro.

Now, I want to install Windows 10 on my surface, using the USB drive I bought. I can install it, however, when entering the system, the touch screen/keyboard are not working. It seems nothing is working...

What should I do with this? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some additional hardware:

- USB drive (I think 8GB is enough, but to be safe - 16GB)
- USB Hub
- Keyboard and Mouse
- Microsoft ISO for re-installing Surface

You get the ISO for re-installing surface [directly from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-au/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage), and they also provide full instruction [here](https://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-au/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/usbrecovery?os=windows-10&=undefined).

I'm sorry but I don't remember the exact steps as I done this only once and it was a bit of trial and error, but in general:

- Burn MS Recovery ISO into the USB (I use [Yumi](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/))
- Connect your USB Hub to the only USB port, and connect your keyboard and mouse to the hub, and also the USB that has your recovery image.
- Boot menu (volume down + power) and choose boot from USB