# Reinstall Win10 from scratch on Surface Pro 4

Tags: windows-10, reinstall, microsoft-surface-pro-4

I would like to have a fresh install of Windows 10 on my Surface Pro 4 because the software is acting up so much. But everything Microsoft is saying is to create the Win10 Recovery Drive from the settings menu.

This is the most similar post I could find,
[Install Windows 10 from scratch on surface pro](https://superuser.com/questions/1149224/install-windows-10-from-scratch-on-surface-pro),
and it makes mention that you can download the ISO Image Surface Pro 4 from microsoft. But they changed the page and still tells you to use the recovery disk you create from within windows.

I need a fresh install, without any drivers or anything from my previous installation.
Is it possible just to use a generic Win10 1709 ISO, and have it work. then just download the fresh drivers from Microsoft afterwards, or will it need the drivers in the middle of the install and not finish the windows install.

Comment: Microsoft has a site to download the recovery image if you cannot create one. Have you tried this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/surfacerecoveryimage

Comment: @music2myear Yes, I went to that webpage, it has me put my serial number in, and then instead of giving me a download link, it tells me just to go to the windows built-in recovery disk creator.

Comment: Just download and install the latest Win 10 version from the media creation tool. Then you download and install the firmware/driver pack for the surface pro matching your version. It’s really quite simple. In other words, there is NOT a special version of Windows to install on the surface pro.

Comment: I'll try that media creation tool. The "make recovery disk" didn't do anything for me. It was a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

As @appleoddity said in his comments, I just downloaded the basic Windows ISO and installed it from scratch. I tried the media creation tool but it crashed so i had to find another way.

1. I downloaded the newest Win 10 ISO from [windowsiso.net](http://windowsiso.net). (Unofficial ISO source but I've trusted and used it for the last year)
2. Wrote that ISO to my thumb drive using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie). (My USB writer of choice)
3. Configured UEFI Firmware to boot to USB. (power button + volume button)
4. Ran installation and wiped disk.
5. Downloaded MSI drivers package for surface pro 4
6. OPTIONALLY: turn BitLocker back on.

This is what I wanted, and this is what worked. My concern was that this being a surface, that it had special requirements or that it had a specific image we had to use like Android tablets have.

Answer (score -1):

Resetting lets you choose whether to keep your files or remove them, and then reinstalls Windows.

Reference **Restore or reset Surface** for detail steps:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4023533/surface-restore-or-reset-surface

Comment: Resetting is NOT what I want to do. I have problems with the OS installation as it currently is and that is the part I want to get rid of. Resetting basically would just get rid of your user account or similarly trier's getting rid of the programs too but it leaves the base OS and the drivers.

Comment: With Windows 10 that